# Slack Block Kit - trigger http request on modal submit

Tags: slack-api, slack-block-kit

I have this json for my modal to use in slack:

```
{
    "type": "modal",
    "title": {
      "type": "plain_text",
      "text": "title",
      "emoji": true,
    },
    "submit": {
      "type": "plain_text",
      "text": "Submit",
      "emoji": true,
    },
    "close": {
      "type": "plain_text",
      "text": "Cancel",
      "emoji": true,
    },
    "blocks": [
      {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
          "type": "plain_text",
          "text": "Adauga un eveniment pe eRadauti",
          "emoji": true,
        },
      },
      {
        "type": "divider",
      },
      {
        "block_id": "title",
        "type": "input",
        "element": {
          "type": "plain_text_input",
          "action_id": "data",
        },
       ...
    ],
  };
```

After I complete the form and I press submit how can I trigger an http request without setting `Interactivity Request Url` or if there is a way to set multiple end points to trigger based on `/` command